# How do I make my orange's randomizefall python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I been trying to make it so my orange's fall randomly between 100 - 650 width and -200 height but it the code I put is not working, the code I'm trying right know makes my orange only keep randomizing right how do I make it randomize randomly and not just randomizing right https://gyazo.com/928b117fb01d9050ac2c50cb1d2f269f

My randomizing code

```
run = True
while run:
# [...]


    for Platform in platforms:
        if orange1.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            orange1.speed += 1
            orange1.x = random.randint(Orange.rect.x,Orange.rect.x + Orange.rect.width)
            orange1.y = random.randrange(0, 1 + 12)
```

My full code

```
https://pastebin.com/aiWMQ5b5
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're drawing the bitmap at the `orange_rect` Rect rather than the object's location `self.rect`.  Later on your change the `self.rect` to move the orange, but this doesn't effect the rect returned by `Orange.orange` bitmap's `.get_rect()`.  The root of the problem is that there's two Rects when only a single one is needed.

```
class Orange:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft =(self.x,self.y)                             # <--here
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
 
        orange_rect = self.orange.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # <<--HERE
        orange_rect.centerx -= 2
        orange_rect.centery += 2
        window.blit(self.orange,orange_rect)                           # <--HERE
```

I would re-work this to use only a single rectangle:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH=500
WINDOW_HEIGHT=700

class Orange:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.orange = pygame.image.load("Orange_1.png")
        self.orange = pygame.transform.scale(self.orange,(self.orange.get_width()//25, self.orange.get_height()//25))

        self.rect = self.orange.get_rect()   # get the rect, and set the position
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw( self ):
        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.rect)
        window.blit( self.orange, self.rect )

    def fall( self, amount ):
        self.rect.y += amount
        if ( self.rect.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
            self.randomReset()  # restart at the top

    def randomReset( self ):
        """ Reposition the fruit somewhat randomly """
        self.speed += 1
        self.x = random.randint( self.rect.x, self.rect.x + self.rect.width)
        self.y = -self.rect.height   # start just off-screen
        # keep on-screen
        if ( self.x < 0 or self.x > WINDOW_WIDTH ):
            screen_eighth = WINDOW_WIDTH // 8
            self.x = random.randint( screen_eighth, WINDOW_WIDTH-screen_eighth )
```

When you write Object Oriented code, on of the main ideas is that the data contained within the code is the "property" of the object, and that outside code shouldn't be touching things like your `Orange.x`.  With this in mind, I have created functions to support the necessary operations on the `Orange` class.

So instead of calling:

```
for Orange in oranges:
    Orange.y += playerman.speed

for Platform in platforms:
    if orange1.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
        orange1.speed += 1
        orange1.x = random.randint(Orange.rect.x,Orange.rect.x + Orange.rect.width)
        orange1.y = random.randrange(0, 1 + 12)
```

We ask the Orange Class to perform the changes to itself, calling member functions:

```
for Orange in oranges:
    Orange.fall( playerman.speed )

for Platform in platforms:
    if orange1.rect.colliderect( Platform.rect ):
        orange1.randomReset()
```

This keeps all the `Orange` functionality inside the class.  This helps prevent side-effect bugs.

Comment: Um, so I'm getting this error ```raise ValueError("empty range for randrange()")
ValueError: empty range for randrange()``` I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but I dubbed check if I changed everything that was needed to be changed but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Windowman - Ah! Please see edit to `randomReset()`

Comment: ```        self.y = random.randrange( -self.rect.height )  # start just off-screen
```

Comment: @Windowman - Yep, I should have removed the `random.randrange`, so the line just becomes: `self.y = -self.rect.height`  We just move the orange somewhere random-x to what it was, and just off the top of the screen.  Eventually you need checks here so it doesn't wander off the screen.  Maybe I'll add that.

Comment: My orange is not going back to the top. it keeps falling.

Comment: @Windowman - Please add the changes I just made to `Orange.fall()`, except no commented-out.  You'll need to add a `WINDOW_HEIGHT=500` global too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224129/discussion-between-kingsley-and-window-man).